# How to configure sudoers to allow running sudo command under other group and user name?

Tags: permissions, sudo

How to configure `sudoers` to prevent having the `Sorry, user ****** is not allowed to execute` error message.

*Background*

For the purpose of testing how a python script under a less privileged user and group daemon account, there is a need to run:

```
$ sudo -u _denyhosts -g _denyhosts python /usr/local/bin/denyhosts.py 
-c /usr/share/denyhosts/denyhosts.cfg -n --purge --sync --verbose
```

The result is:

```
Sorry, user ****** is not allowed to execute 
'/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/denyhosts.py -c /usr/share/denyhosts/denyhosts.cfg 
-n --purge --sync --verbose' as _denyhosts:_denyhosts on ***.***.***.
```

The guess is that this command fails due to an extra configuration required in `sudoers`.

```
$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for *** on this host:
    editor=/usr/bin/nano, env_reset, env_keep+=BLOCKSIZE, env_keep+="COLORFGBG
    COLORTERM", env_keep+=__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING, env_keep+="CHARSET LANG
    LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY
    LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME", env_keep+="LINES COLUMNS", env_keep+=LSCOLORS,
    env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK, env_keep+=TZ, env_keep+="DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION
    XAUTHORITY", env_keep+="EDITOR VISUAL", env_keep+="HOME MAIL"

User *** may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) ALL
```

Already tried to add the group `_denyhosts` to `sudoers` by executing `sudo visudo` and inserting the line:

```
%_denyhosts    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Saving and trying again does not improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `%_denyhosts    ALL=(ALL) ALL` means that users in the `_denyhosts` group are allowed to run any command as any user. This isn't what you're trying to do: you need to allow the user `******` to run commands as the user `_denyhosts` and the group `_denyhosts`. Something like:

```
****** ALL = (_denyhosts : _denyhosts) ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ensure that even though users in _denyhosts has been added to the sudoers file, that the users you want to be able to execute this command are added to the group _denyhosts in /etc/group.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/group
*snip*
_denyhosts:x:###:username1,username2,username3
```

Save the the 'group' file and retry.